# Is this function enough for preventing SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-injection, server-side

I created this simple function and want to know that if it is enough for preventing SQL Injection.

```
$sub_username = encr(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']));
$sub_password = encr(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']));

$sql = "SELECT password FROM login WHERE username='$sub_username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


function encr($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
}
```

Comment: Why not just use prepared statements? Much easier than mangling your input...

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I know, but I wanted to ask if it can work.

Comment: I would also recommend using `password_hash()`.

Comment: well, if you want to know. This code is just a random heap of function calls that is incidentally prone to SQL injection.You got to use prepared statements because they won't let an SQL injection in, no matter what you do.

Comment: What do you think htmlspecialchars does, and why do you think it would help with SQL injection?

Comment: It's not only not enough. It's actually counterproductive, since it undos the escaping when used in this combination.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string wont protect from `1 or 1=1`

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for your help!